# Preprocessor: concat previous line number in the name of a structure

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, c++03

I know how to declare a struct where the name contains the current line number. The following code works as expected.

```
#define CREATE_NAME_CONCAT_(X, Y) X ## Y
#define CREATE_NAME_CONCAT(X, Y) CREATE_NAME_CONCAT_(X, Y)
#define CREATE_FOO_NAME CREATE_NAME_CONCAT(Foo_, __LINE__)
struct CREATE_FOO_NAME { int x; };
typedef Foo_4 Foo;
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.x = 42; 
    return 0;
}
```

**How can I write the typedef line using the previous line number ?** The following code doesn't work:

```
#define CREATE_NAME_CONCAT_(X, Y) X ## Y
#define CREATE_NAME_CONCAT(X, Y) CREATE_NAME_CONCAT_(X, Y)
#define CREATE_FOO_NAME CREATE_NAME_CONCAT(Foo_, __LINE__)
struct CREATE_FOO_NAME { int x; };
typedef CREATE_NAME_CONCAT(Foo_, __LINE__-1) Foo;
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.x = 42; 
    return 0;
}
```

*Note 1: yes I have a good reason to do that*

*Note 2: I don't use C++11 or more recent*

*Note 3: I don't want to debate notes 1 & 2*

Comment: try https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html though note by default it only works up to `256`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is likely a better way

Comment: @AlanBirtles: look at notes, please...

Comment: I did read your notes, still doesn't mean there isn't a better way than trying to hack around the limitations of the preprocessor, e.g. numerical template arguments would allow the required maths that you need

Comment: @AlanBirtles: actually, `BOOST_PP_DEC(__LINE__)` instead of `__LINE__ - 1` seems do the job. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, as you expected, it doesn't work when `__LINE__ > 256`. Still open then...

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is pretty limited, the best solution is to not use it at all. You can accomplish something similar with templates:

```
template <int>
struct FooT;
template <>
struct FooT<__LINE__> { int x; };
typedef FooT<__LINE__-1> Foo;

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.x = 42; 
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if this meets your requirements as they seem to be secret.